# Convert Color[] or Color32[] into the YV12, NV21 or YUV_420_888 image format

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-processing

Unity's `WebCamTexture` give access to the `Color[]` or `Color32[]` of the underlying texture. Based on any of them, I would like to find a way to convert the texture to the YV12, NV21 or YUV_420_888 image format (any). I do not have a background in image processing so it is very possible that my question is framed incorrectly so I would appreciate any insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is worth a try

```
  var texture = new Texture2D(tex.width, tex.height, TextureFormat.YUY2, tex.mipmapCount > 1); 
  texture.SetPixels32(WebCamTexture.Color32);
  texture.Apply();
```

The idea is to get the colour 32 and send it to a new texture. this will be resource-heavy keep the calls to this as few as possible

Comment: instead of `WebCamTexture.Color32` I guess you mean [`WebCamTexture.GetPixels32()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixels32.html) ? and `dstTexture` should probably rather be `texture`

Comment: @derHugo yes, exactly.

Comment: It seems that TextureFormat does't have an YV12 property. Is it supposed to have one?

Comment: Hey, Sorry about that. I do not think YV12 might be written as YUY2 https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html you can check here hope this helps as it tells you all the enums as it cannot really in code have exact names. 

according to me in TextureFormat as 12 and other things refer to it as depth and height. you should basically change the tex.width and height to the necessary

please do tell me if this helps, then I will change the answer code accordingly so this might help people in the future. Thanks :D